# How to replace "|PersonId|" with "PersonId(SourceSystemId)" in a data file by batch?

Tags: batch-file, replace

How can I replace "|PersonId|" with "PersonId(SourceSystemId)" in a data file by batch? There are several places need to be replaced.

Thanks,

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149373/388389

Answer (score 1):

Try with   [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
call replacer.bat "C:\data.file" "|PersonId|" "PersonId(SourceSystemId)"
```

Comment: Hi Npocmaka, Thank you for your info. I used this script. But it replaced all columns to PersonId(SourceSystemId)...Can you tell me which one I need modify? I used script https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat. Thanks,

Comment: @DBALUKEHUANG - so there places where it should not be replaced? You didn't specified this in your question.I still don't know how I can help without knowing when and when not it should be replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured it out with https://www.dostips.com/?t=batch.findandreplace. The script works for me. Much appreciate and best regards,